# IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2017.2 keeps asking proxy credentials

Tags: intellij-idea

I am behind an enterprise firewall, have checked "Auto-detect proxy settings" in System Settings -> HTTP Proxy. I entered the correct credentials and checked "Remember". I know the credentials are correct, as I am able, for example, to download and install plugins.

However, IntelliJ keeps asking me periodically to re-enter the proxy credentials. Why?

Comment: There are related reports on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-140044,  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-184584, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-149380

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was changing proxy setting to "No Proxy" from "Auto-detect".
Idea retrieves proxy settings anyway from Windows.

Version:2019.3

[image]

Comment: @marc_s looks like we're both in the same situation. If either of us find the solution to this proxy/SSL thing we'll share.

Comment: if your license is deactivated, go into evaluation mode (if you can), and make the edits in the proxy settings suggested above, then go to Help->Register. Jetbrains should fix this asap. Nothing worse than punishing your customers with a broken license system.

Answer (score 0):

Raising a case they said the SSL certificate gets replaced via the proxy.

I was baffled as it works for some people and not others. People sitting next to each other!

Essentially the proxy gets in the way (from all non-JDK reports) and this is why you can't see the **Last Seen** dates in the site for all licensees.

The KB: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544889-SignatureException-Signature-doesn-t-match-or-Signature-length-not-correct-got-256-but-was-expecting-512

**Solution:**

The only alternative is to use the Offline Activation codes for each user who will need to login to https://JetBrains.com and get their individual Offline Activation code. Then activate the software offline. Help Menu > Register.